# Livecode return response headers

Tags: livecode

I am working on wordpress REST API and I need to get all the posts available. And I need to know how many pages are available based on number of posts per page.

Based on this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-retrieving-data--cms-24694), I can retrieve those info from `X-WP-TotalPages` and `X-WP-Total` response headers.

The X-WP-TotalPages and X-WP-Total response headers are extremely useful when creating pagination using the WP REST API as they list the total number of pages and the total number of posts respectively.

But when I execute a `GET` requests, no headers response are available. I can retrieve the other response though like the posts.

How do I return response headers in livecode?

Headers I set:

`put "Content-Type: application/json" & cr after tHeader
 put "Cache-Control: no-cache" & cr after tHeader
 set the httpheaders to tHeader`

Comment: Looking in the dictionary, it looks like you'd use `libURLLastRHHeaders()` ... does that work ?

Comment: @uliwitness I'll check on that later. I found another way to solve my problem aside from relying on the response headers, that is why.

Comment: If that other solution works, please leave a comment or answer with that solution here, so others who have the same question can find the answer :-)

Comment: @uliwitness the solution is not related to my question. it is another way around :)